# How to convert List<String> to an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arrays, api, types, casting

[This API call](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.5/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#getChildren%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) returns a potentially large List<String>, which is not sorted. I need to sort it, search it, and access random elements. Currently the List is implemented by an ArrayList (I checked the source), but at some unknown point in the future the API developers may choose to switch to a LinkedList implementation (without changing the interface).

Sorting, searching, accessing a potentially large LinkedList would be extremely slow and unacceptable for my program. Therefore I need to convert the List to an ArrayList to ensure the practical efficiency of my program. However, since the List is most likely an ArrayList already, it would be inefficient to needlessly create a new ArrayList copy of the List.

Given these constraints, I have come up with the following method to convert a List into an ArrayList:

```
private static <T> ArrayList<T> asArrayList(List<T> list) {
  if (list instanceof ArrayList) {
    return (ArrayList<T>) (list);
  } else {
    return new ArrayList<T>(list);
  }
}
```

My question is this: Is this the most efficient way to work with a List with an unknown implementation? Is there a better way to convert a List to an ArrayList? Is there a better option than converting the List into an ArrayList?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how large it could be (size)? Unless it can be really big and causes performance issue, I would just use the copy constructor.

Comment: Probably between 5,000 and 50,000, and the method would be called tens of thousands of times.

Comment: Using the copy constructor on a list with 100,000 items takes less than 0.5ms on my desktop pc (after JIT has kicked in). Now the cast is about 1,000x faster ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really get much simpler than what you've got - looks about as efficient as it could possibly be to me.

That said, this sounds very much like premature optimisation - you should only really need to worry about this if and when the author of the API you're using changes to a `LinkedList`. If you worry about it now, you are likely to spend a lot of time and effort planning for a future scenario that may not even come to pass - this is time that might be better spent finding other issues to fix. Presumably the only time you'll be changing versions of the API is between versions of your own application - handle the issue at that point, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see yourself, the code is simple and it is efficient inasmuch as it only creates a copy if it is necessary.

So the answer is that there is no significantly better option, save for a completely different type of solution, something that sorts your list as well, for example.

(Bear in mind that this level of optimisation is rarely required, so it's not a very frequent problem.)

Update: Just an afterthoughtL as a general rule, well-written APIs don't return data types that are inappropriate for the amount of data they are likely to contain. That is not to say you should trust them blindly, but it's not a completely unreasonable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

> Sorting, searching, accessing a potentially large LinkedList would be extremely slow and unacceptable for my program.

Actually, it is not as bad as that.  IIRC, the Collections.sort methods copy the list to a temporary array, sort the array, `clear()` the original list and copy the array back to it.  For large enough lists, the `O(NlogN)` sorting phase will dominate the `O(N)` copying phases.

Answer (score 0):

Java collections that support efficient random access implement the RandomAccess marker interface. For such a list you could just run `Collections.sort` on the list directly. For lists without random access you should probably dump the list to an array using one of its `toArray` methods, sort that array, then wrap it into a random-access `List`.

```
T[] array = (T[])list.toArray(); // just suppress the warning if the compiler worries about unsafe cast
Arrays.sort(array);
List<T> sortedList = Arrays.asList(array);
```

I think `Arrays.asList` actually creates an `ArrayList`, so you could try casting its result, if you like.

`Collections.sort` is efficient for all `List` implementations, as long as they provide an efficient `ListIterator`. The method dumps the list into an array, sorts that, then uses the `ListIterator` to copy the values back into the list in O(n).

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` doesn't create an arraylist (well, it sort of does, as it returns an `Arrays.ArrayList` inner class type. :)) but a list that is backed by the actual array.

Comment: Ah ok. That's why naming your classes matters. Two classes with the same name in the same package, one being a public top-level class and the other being an inner class, is just confusing. :)

Comment: Ask me how I found this out :)